# The simplest possible getopt program I can get?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, gnu, getopt

After doing some reading on this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) on how to use `getopt()`, I'm trying to get a small example.

What I want, is something like:

```
./prog -v      # show me prog version
./prog -f filename  # just show me the filename I entered from the command line
```

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, *argv[]) {
     char VER[] = "0.1.1";
     int opt;
     opt = getopt(argc, argv, "vf:");
     char *filename;

      while (opt != -1) {
           switch(opt) {
            case 'v':
                printf("version is %s", VER);
                break;
            case 'f':
                filename = optarg;
                break;
            }
     }
    printf("The filename was %s", filename);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code with:

```
$ gcc prog.c -o prog -Wall -Wextra
```

I can't seem to understand when I run it with `-v` option it never stops printing the version
and with `-f filename` it stops there and never prints the filename I entered.

Comment: Does that even compile?  What's the `"vf"` in the signature of `main`?

Comment: Assuming that you read all the text in my question, yes it compiles otherwise i wouldn't ask about problems that occur when i run the program. v and f are the options available (-v and -f). The : after f means that -f wants one more parameter from the user.

Comment: Well, since what you posted *didn't* compile, I think my question was reasonable.

Comment: Yes you are correct. And my vf part was also reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't stop because you only call `getopt()` once.  A possible fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char VER[] = "0.1.1";
    int opt;
    const char *filename = "unspecified";

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "vf:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'v':
                printf("version is %s\n", VER);
                break;
            case 'f':
                filename = optarg;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-v][-f file]\n", argv[0]);
                return(1);
        }
    }
    printf("The filename was %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've made sure that `filename` is initialized, that `printf()` outputs end with a newline, and that the error cases are reported.

Here's another, slightly more complex, example program:

```
/* Example 1 - using POSIX standard getopt() */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    int i;
    int bflag = 0;
    int aflag = 0;
    int errflag = 0;
    char *ifile = 0;
    char *ofile = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, ":abf:o:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            if (bflag)
                errflag++;
            else
                aflag++;
            break;
        case 'b':
            if (aflag)
                errflag++;
            else
                bflag++;
            break;
        case 'f':
            ifile = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            ofile = optarg;
            break;
        case ':':   /* -f or -o without operand */
            fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an operand\n", optopt);
            errflag++;
            break;
        case '?':
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized option: -%c\n", optopt);
            errflag++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (errflag)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-a|-b][-f in][-o out] [file ...]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(2);
    }

    printf("Flags: a = %d, b = %d\n", aflag, bflag);
    if (ifile != 0)
        printf("Input: %s\n", ifile);
    if (ofile != 0)
        printf("Output: %s\n", ofile);
    printf("Argc = %d, OptInd = %d\n", argc, optind);
    for (i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        printf("File: %s\n", argv[i]);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It is based on an example from a Sun manual.  The `-a` and `-b` options are mutually exclusive.  It illustrates (the limitations of) POSIX `getopt()` with 'optional arguments' enabled (the leading `:` on the option string).  It also prints out its inputs at the end.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, your examples are really enlightening.

Comment: @yaku add  printf("The filename was %s\n", filename); statement in case 'f', and remove after while. because if you use option v then also will print filename as unspecified.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm glad.  That's one of a series of example programs collected and completed while I was writing a replacement for `getopt()`.  So, it was a simple copy/paste to provide it.

Comment: @Gangadhar: I'm not sure I completely understand. Printing the filename in the `case 'f'` option is certainly feasible, but whether it is correct depends on what you want to do if the user runs `prog -f file1 -f file2 -v -- file3`. The repeated `-f` will, in the existing code, take the last value (`file2`); if you print in the `switch`, you'll see both `file1` and `file2`, but unless you process the file then, it could lead to confusion. Considering what to do about repeated options is important — you can allow it and process each file as you go, or save the names for later, or reject it.

Comment: @Gangadhar I made the changes you suggested.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Completley Understood. Entirely dependent on want do we expects, if we give particular option.thanks again for such a clear explaination.

Comment: @yaku try experiments with the example which is given by JonathanLeffler .would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
case 'v':
    printf("version is %s", VER);
    break;
```

the `break` is breaking you out of the `switch` statement, not out of the `while` loop, so the `while` loop continues and you go on forever because `opt` never changes. You're missing some logic, here, you probably want to be calling `getopt()` again somewhere in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, *argv[], "vf")   


getopt.c:5:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before â*â token
getopt.c:5:28: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before string constant
```

this should be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
```

modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     char VER[] = "0.1.1";
     int opt;
   opt = getopt(argc, argv, "vf:");
     char *filename;

      while (opt != -1) {
           switch(opt) {
            case 'v':
                printf("version is %s\n", VER);
                exit(0);
            case 'f':
             //   filename = optarg;
                 printf("The filename was %s\n", argv[2]);
                exit(0);


            }
     }
    return 0;
```