# Program in C to read arguments

Tags: c, getopt

I started to learn C and I want to create a program which will take  2 obligatory arguments and 1 optional. ` 
This question may sound elementary but I have difficulty in understanding it. 
So basically what I want to do is to call the program like this:

```
myfile -n name -a age -g grade
```

So when I call it this will be valid: `myfile john 22 20`
`Name` and `age` are `obligatory`. So `name` is a string, `age` is a number between 0 and 100. 
And `grade` is `optional` and can be a number. If it isn't defined then the value of it will be 0.

I tried to do it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    FILE *fp;
    char *filename = "student.txt";

    char name;
    int age, grade;
    if( (fp = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL) {
        // show error 
        printf("Error."); 
     }
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Error.");
        return;
    }
    int ich = 0;
    while ((ich = getopt (argc, argv, "abc")) != -1) {
        switch (ich) {
            case 'a': 
                name = argv[1];
                break;
            case 'b': 
                age = argv[2];  
                if not (age >= 0 && age<100) {
                    printf("Error."); 
                }
                break;
            case 'c': 
                grade = argv[3];
                if (grade == NULL) {
                    grade = 0;
                }
                break;
            default: 
                break;
        }
  }
```

I want to use pointer `optarg` to have access to the arguments.
I get this error `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` 
I really need help. Please, can someone help me. I really need help. :(

Here is [my tutorialspoint fiddle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUTB1RW9zMnNOSUE)

Comment: Here `if(argc!=2)`, you have said two arguments are obligatory - but the program name is supplied as the first argument, so you must check `if(argc < 3)`, because you also have optional arguments.

Comment: `getopt()` is used to process options like `program -a age -ggrade -n name -v` (with the `-X` hyphen-letter parts being the crucial part).  If you simply want three arguments in sequence, you don't need `getopt()`.  Note that using `getopt()` would mean the user could also invoke `program -vn name -aage -g grade` (resequencing the order of the arguments, and optional space between option letter and option string).  I've hypothesized a `-v` option for 'verbose' mode, and that does not take an argument.

Comment: @WeatherVane that is my mistake. Thank you for editing it.

Comment: Note that the comment `//check if file exists` followed by the code `if( (fp = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL) {` basically ensures that the file is empty and so may as well not exist — it could be written to, and will have been created if it did not already exist.  The comment and the code are somewhat in disagreement with each other — a depressingly common state of affairs even in code written by professionals.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry if my question sounds elementary. Can you give  the most simplest example using getopt() and I really don't get what is the function of abc inside this:  (ich = getopt (argc, argv, "abc")? Thank you for your time

Comment: @JonathanLeffler all those mistakes are because I tried many ways to make it works and I couldn't do it :(

Comment: I suggest you take a good look at my answer to [The simplest possible `getopt()` program I can get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554775/the-simplest-possible-getopt-program-i-can-get/18554885#18554885).  If that isn't sufficient help, update your question with the extra information about what you're still confused about, and add a comment addressed to me with the `@Jonathan` notation so I know to look again.  Note that `"abc"` looks for options without arguments.  Are you using Linux (GNU) `getopt()` or another sub-species?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122701/discussion-between-egjupss-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122706/discussion-between-egjupss-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion etc, I created this code based on the code from the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char *arg0 = 0;
static void usage(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -n name -a age [-g grade]\n", arg0);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *filename = "student.txt";
    char *name = 0;
    int age = 0;
    int grade = 22;

    arg0 = argv[0];

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:a:g:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'n':
            name = optarg;
            break;
        case 'a':
            age = atoi(optarg);
            if (age <= 0 || age >= 100)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Age '%s' out of range 1..99\n", optarg);
                usage();
            }
            break;
        case 'g':
            grade = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    if (name == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "You did not specify a name\n");
        usage();
    }
    if (age == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "You did not specify an age\n");
        usage();
    }
    if (optind != argc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Extra arguments provided (starting with '%s')\n", argv[optind]);
        usage();
    }

    // check if file exists
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "w")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s, %d, %d\n", name, age, grade);
        fprintf(fp, "%s, %d, %d\n", name, age, grade);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for writing\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example runs

Program name: `go59`

```
$ go59
You did not specify a name
Usage: go59 -n name -a age [-g grade]
$ go59 -n Rita
You did not specify an age
Usage: go59 -n name -a age [-g grade]
$ go59 -n Rita -a 23
Rita, 23, 22
$ go59 -n Andromeda -a 23 -g 97
Andromeda, 23, 97
$ go59 -n Andromeda -a 23 -g 97 apoplexy
Extra arguments provided (starting with 'apoplexy')
Usage: go59 -n name -a age [-g grade]
$ go59 -n Andromeda -a 23 -g 97 --
Andromeda, 23, 97
$ go59 -n Andromeda -a -1 -g 97 --
Age '-1' out of range 1..99
Usage: go59 -n name -a age [-g grade]
$ go59 -n Andromeda -a 0 -g 97 --
Age '0' out of range 1..99
Usage: go59 -n name -a age [-g grade]
$
```

Note that the code doesn't zap the `student.txt` file until it knows that the arguments it was given are valid enough.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C. The most important concept about C is not to reinvent the wheel. The argument style you are looking for is the GNU standard. That being said, the GNU has already wrote all the C code to do this work for you (as far as parsing argc and argv). Look into GNU's [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) shared library. If you're on Linux then you already have it.

Comment: It's intriguing that you suggest the use of the `getopt` 'library' (function) when in fact the OP is already doing that, but is having difficulty seeing how to use it.  The pointer to the GNU documentation is useful.